# Is there a Java equivalent of vectorization from numpy?

Tags: java, multithreading, numpy, vectorization

I recently came across vectorization in python using numpy library, to make use of parallel computing.
Which immediately had me asking is there a java equivalent of this, for eg. dividing all Integers in an array by some constant, is there a way that I can invoke this computation on different parts of the array simultaneously?
I am aware that java supports multithreading, but I am yet to make use of it in a program, can multithreading be a solution to this problem in java?

Comment: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/338

Comment: `vectorization` in `numpy` really means using the compiled building blocks to work on the whole array. This contrasts with slower iterations in interpreted python. Java doesn't have that interpreted vs compiled issue.